# SQL - Changing column types from text to date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table that contains two columns that I'd like to change their data type. Both are currently just declared as text but I'd like to change DateSent to a date and TimeSent to a time. The data is currently in MM/DD/YYYY format for date and HH:MM (24h) for time.

How can this be done? And when I add data in the future, will it automatically convert any reasonable dates and times format correctly?

Comment: Conversion isn't automatically. You should have a look at STR_TO_DATE and DATE_FORMAT in the [function reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/func-op-summary-ref.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one step.  What you will need to do is to add a new column for your date, and then populate it using an UPDATE statement that converts the string to a date; using CAST('mm/dd/yyyy' AS DATE).  Then you can delete your old column, and rename the new one.

The same steps for the column holding the time data.

You will need to add new data in the future in the correct types; date or time.

---

Per OP request I'll edit Mark's answer with a sample query

**SAMPLE UPDATE QUERY:**

```
UPDATE table_name t,
(
    SELECT
        id, 
        CAST(col1 AS DATE) as update_col1
        CAST(col2 AS TIME) as update_col2
    FROM table_name
) as t1
SET t.col1 = t1.update_col1, t.col2 = t1.update_col2
WHERE t.id = t1.id
```

Comment: i believe the OP wants to keep the columns separate.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Does Marks answer suggest anything else: `The same steps for the column holding the time data` ...

Comment: @VMai shouldn't it be cast as date and not datetime then?

Comment: @JohnRuddell It would be better, but I would prefer [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) anyway :-)

Comment: @VMai as would I :) hence the upvote on your comment

Comment: I was able to create two new columns (named them dates and times, of data types date and time respectively) but i still have not been able to get the update to work to move the data in DatesSent to dates and TimesSent to times.

Comment: @sakau2007 i just edited Mark's answer with a sample query to follow for updating

Comment: Still getting it wrong:
`UPDATE Ballers.messages t, /* table name is messages, in database Ballers */
(
SELECT
id,  /* ???? */
CAST(DateSent AS DATE) as update_col1 /* This should cast DateSent (text) as a date and store it in t1.update_col1 */
CAST(TimeSent AS TIME) as update_col2 /* This should cast TimeSent (text) as a time and store it in t1.update_col2 */
FROM Ballers.messages
) as t1
SET t.DateSent = t1.update_col1, t.TimeSent = t1.update_col2
WHERE Ballers.messages.id = t1.id;`
What am I doing wrong?  (argh: cant get code to format right in comments)

Comment: @sakau2007 try running the select query without update.. just see if it does the cast correctly. if it does then i'm not sure why it wouldn't work